# How do I combine two lists that are unequal in length?

Tags: python

I have two lists that I'm trying to combine, one is a list of cities, and another is a list of states.

Here's what my city list looks like:

```
print(combined_city_list)
[['Los Angeles', 'Long Beach', 'Anaheim'], ['Dallas', 'Fort Worth'], ['Miami', 'Fort Lauderdale'], ['Minneapolis', 'St Paul'], ['Louisville', 'Jefferson County'], ['North Port', 'Sarasota', 'Bradenton'], ['Winston', 'Salem'], ['Santa Maria', 'Santa Barbara'], ['Crestview', 'Fort Walton Beach', 'Destin'], ['Macon', 'Bibb County'], ['Champaign', 'Urbana'], ['Lafayette', 'West Lafayette'], ['California', 'Lexington Park'], ['Pinehurst', 'Southern Pines'], ['Hermiston', 'Pendleton'], ['Wisconsin Rapids', 'Marshfield'], ['Arkansas City', 'Winfield']]
```

Here's what my state list looks like:

```
print(combined_state_list)
[[' CA'], [' TX'], [' FL'], [' MN'], [' KY'], [' FL'], [' NC'], [' CA'], [' FL'], [' GA'], [' IL'], [' IN'], [' MD'], [' NC'], [' OR'], [' WI'], [' KS']]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
combined_state_short = [i[0] for i in combined_state_list]

combined_city_state = []
for c, s in zip (combined_city_list, combined_state_list):
    for i in c:
        combined_city_state = str(i) + ',' + str(s)

print(combined_city_state)
```

I get this as the output:

```
Winfield,[' KS']
```

I want something like this:

```
['Los Angeles, CA', 'Long Beach, CA' ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
newlist = [z + ',' + y[0]  for x , y in zip(combined_city_list,combined_state_list) for z in x]
```

Comment: That still has sublists for each state. I think a flat list is desired.

Comment: @JosephSible if that is the case just need move the 2nd for loop at the end :-)

Comment: Thank you both!  I just realized that I've been overwriting my combined_city_state list and just needed to add an intermediary variable to append.

Comment: @Lee anyway the problem get resolved :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
[city + ',' + state for (cities, (state, *_)) in zip(combined_city_list, combined_state_list) for city in cities]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more clear for beginner in that form:

```
new_list = []
for cities, state in zip(combined_city_list, combined_state_list):
    for city in cities:
        new_list.append(city + ',' + state[0])
new_list
```